# Not able to run basic example of pycparser

Tags: pycparser

I am trying to start with pycparser and was trying to run the examples given on the [github repo](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser/blob/master/examples/using_gcc_E_libc.py). I only changed the path of the file to be parsed after saving the sample c file locally. I get the following error and am not sure if there is some pre-processing step that I am missing?

```
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 89, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "C:/Users/Z003RTRP/Desktop/cparse.py", line 20, in <module>
ast = parse_file(filename, use_cpp=True, cpp_path='gcc', cpp_args=r'-Iutils/fake_libc_include')
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pycparser\__init__.py", line 86, in parse_file
text = preprocess_file(filename, cpp_path, cpp_args)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pycparser\__init__.py", line 49, in preprocess_file
('Original error: %s' % e))
RuntimeError: Unable to invoke 'cpp'.  Make sure its path was passed correctly
Original error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this section of the README](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser#31interaction-with-the-c-preprocessor) - you have to point `cpp_path` to the C preprocessor on your system. For Windows, it recommends downloading a binary build of Clang and using `clang -E`